# "Module "Mage_Newsletter" requires module "Mage_Widget"

Tags: magento-1, newsletter

```
a:4:{i:0;s:55:"Module "Mage_Newsletter" requires module "Mage_Widget".";i:1;s:758:"#0 /home2/ulashlvw/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(851): Mage::throwException('Module "Mage_Ne...')
#1 /home2/ulashlvw/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(815): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_sortModuleDepends(Array)
#2 /home2/ulashlvw/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(318): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_loadDeclaredModules()
#3 /home2/ulashlvw/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(425): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModules()
#4 /home2/ulashlvw/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#5 /home2/ulashlvw/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#6 /home2/ulashlvw/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#7 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento 1 modules are handled inside the **app/etc/modules/ folder** of your website.
Make sure that both `Mage_Newsletter` and `Mage_Widget` is set to **active**.  It is most likely that Mage_Widget is disabled.

Inside `app/etc/modules/Mage_All.xml` :

```
      <Mage_Newsletter>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>core</codePool>
        <depends>
            <Mage_Core/>
            <Mage_Customer/>
            <Mage_Eav/>
            <Mage_Widget/>
       </depends>
    </Mage_Newsletter>`
```

Inside `app/etc/modules/Mage_Widget.xml`:

```
     <Mage_Widget>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>core</codePool>
        <depends>
            <Mage_Cms />
        </depends>
    </Mage_Widget>`
```

Clear cache afterwards : `rm -rf filelocation/var/cache/*`